# How to the numbers that are followed by certain units in regular expression?

Tags: r

Extract the numbers (return only integers) that are followed by the units 'ml' or 'lb' in the following text:

```
myText <- 'At 10am we had 40ml of water, 5 lb of meat, 3lb of salt and 
20 apples.'
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract` with regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract_all(myText, "\\d+(?=\\s*(ml|lb))")[[1]])
#[1] 40  5  3
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps